# Need information about migrating projects from one company to another

Tags: migration

We are in the beginning stages of migrating projects from our current developers Google Platform to an in-house new Google Platform.  We are new to this environment and have setup the Google account and entered billing information.  The current developer has sent two invites for the two projects that they were currently handling for us.  I accepted the invites, however it tells me that we do not have an organization setup.  Do we need to do this to completely take over these two projects ?  The main thing is that I need these sites to continue to stay up and running until we complete the full migration.  I cannot get Google support until an Organization and Organization ID is setup, and am struggling to find any support documentation that fits into exactly what we are trying to do.  Current setup is a 3rd party is handling everything for us...the GCP, etc.  We have setup our own GCP and entered billing information.  What steps does the 3rd party as well as us need to do to complete the migration of these two projects that they sent invites for over to us and remove their responsibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

Here [1] you can see the official procedure to follow in case you would like to migrate a project from an Organization or even a project from a NO-Organization project(Handling special cases).

1.Create a migration plan
2.Assign permissions
3.Configure organization policies
4.Perform the migration

In the guide, it's explained step by step the procedure you will need to follow to reach this migration correctly.

Best Regards
[1] https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration